# Хочу сделать функцию,которая будет выполняться,в случае закрытия скрипта

Tags: python

```
def exit():
   time.sleep(1)
   if скрипт закрывается:
      r = requests.get(url)
```

Подскажите как можно такое сделать,закрытие желательно через крестик

Answer (score 0):

Нашел такой [код](https://python.su/forum/topic/15689/), обрабатывает прерывание по <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>:

```
import sys
import signal
import time


def on_stop(*args):
    print('exit on 3 sec...')
    time.sleep(3)
    sys.exit(0)


for sig in (signal.SIGBREAK, signal.SIGINT, signal.SIGTERM):
    signal.signal(sig, on_stop)

while True:
    print('tick')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Похожий [вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19901493/how-to-detect-program-exited-in-python-on-windows-and-do-something-on-exit/19907688#19907688) на En SO
Еще пару ссылок про сигналы: [1](https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/8814/signal.SIGBREAK), [2](http://john16blog.blogspot.com/2013/02/python-signal.html)